# Why is $0 set to -bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, debconf

First login process name seems to be set to `-bash`, but if I subshell then it becomes `bash`.  for example:

```
root@nowere:~# echo $0
-bash
root@nowere:~# bash
root@nowere:~# echo $0
bash
```

`-bash` is causing some scripts to fail, such as `. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule`

```
exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend -bash
Can't exec "-bash": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/IPC/Open3.pm line 186.
open2: exec of -bash failed at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59
```

Anyone know the reason why `$0` is set to `-bash`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Useless Use of Cat spotted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the output of `echo $0` command is `-bash` it means that  `bash` was invoked as a login shell. `man bash` says somewhere at line 126:

> ```
> A  login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or 
> one started with the --login option.
> ```

See more about here: [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

So your shell is still `/bin/bash` (this can be checked with `echo $SHELL` command) and I suggest you to use that command which give you error as normally:

```
exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend bash
```

Comment: Thanks, it does appears that login is correctly adding the "-" to the  login shell process name.  That answers my question.